# Searching body text in a discussion that contains Outlook email

Tags: search

I have a discussion board in which I have added a large amount of emails. The search function only returns text that is included in the subject. I need to make the body of the email searchable. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Eric,  which version of SharePoint are you using,  In SharePoint 2013 we have something called Indexed columns,  can you check if body field is added onto the Indexed Columns of the discussion list.

I think your Body field is not crawled/indexed by search,  hence it is not searchable.

Hope this helps...

Comment: 2010 I beleive. Yes, complete novice.